Flutter cubit for AlertDialog For NaviGate.pop(context) for Data Not Show Display
*My error is the data add for but homepage not display and hot restart for data is the show Navigate(context) for not rebuild ui please right answer and solution there. *
github link is the here....
https://github.com/IamNikunjParmar/DataBase_Sqflite/tree/master/hive_DataBase_crud/lib
please check this link and my error sol this problem
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text("Emp Details"),
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  EmployeeModal emp = EmployeeModal(
                    id: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                    name: nameController.text,
                    email: emailController.text,
                    number: 45456,
                  );
                  context.read<HomePageCubit>().onInsertEmp(emp);
                  // nameController.clear();
                  // emailController.clear();
                  Navigator.pop(context, true);
                  print("add: $emp");
                },
                child: const Text("Add"),
              ),
            ],
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    label: Text("name"),
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    label: Text("email"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  void onInsertEmp(EmployeeModal emp) {
try {
  emit(const HomePageLoading());
  empHelper.insertEmp(emp);
  final currentState = state;
  if (currentState is HomePageLoaded) {
    final newList = List<EmployeeModal>.from(currentState.empList);
    emit(HomePageLoaded(empList: newList));
    eventBus.fire(EmpDataChanged());
  }
} catch (e) {
  emit(HomePageError(msg: e.toString()));
}

}
